# Ripple effect always coming in rectangle shape on an image in android

Tags: android, onfocus, ripple

I am facing an issue in providing ripple effect in ovel shape on a button with an image background.

right_arrow_ripple_effect.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="#1ddbd9">
<item android:id="@android:id/mask" android:drawable="@android:color/white"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_weather_app_main_right_normal"/>
```

I am setting this file as background to the button layout through my java code in onClick() function.

```
 mRightArrowView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.right_arrow_ripple_effect);
```

On focus, there is a solid square bg behind this button. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

you can use circleImageView here, for example:

```
<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/profile_image"
    android:layout_width="96dp"
    android:layout_height="96dp"
    android:src="@drawable/profile"
    app:border_width="2dp"
    app:border_color="#FF000000"/>
```

to use this you need to add the following to your dependencies:

```
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0'
```

after you set this image as clickable in your code you'll get the desired effect.

link to github project:
https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView

I hope this helps :)

Comment: Hi I have dependency on other segments of the code and can not touch my layout files. I have to make changes in either java code or drawable folder xml files to achieve this.